# No value given for one or more required parameters.What is error in query

Tags: winforms, ms-access, c#-3.0

```
  if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { conn.Open(); }
  string sql = "SELECT debit.tblgltransactions AS Debit,credit.tblgltransactions AS Credit,glaccounttype.tblglaccounttypes  from tblgltransactions,tblglaccounttypes where glaccounttype.tblglaccounttypes='" + cmbGeneralLedgerAccounts + "'and transactiondate.tblgltransactions='"+dtpFromDate+"'AND '"+dtpToDate+"'";
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
  OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  oda.Fill(dt);
  dgvGeneralLedger.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
  if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); }
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do is change your query to use parameters instead of putting the values directly in as strings. Your current approach is how SQL injection attacks happen. Parameterized queries have other advantages beyond security: they provide a clearer separation of "code" (the query) and "data" (the parameters), and there's less room for conversions (such as the date part) to go wrong.

Comment: The obvious error here is the `AND '"+dtpToDate+"'";`, you're not comparing it to anything which is likely not desired. You're also missing spaces. But the error message refers to something else entirely, a field that's mistyped or not referenced in the `FROM` clause

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed a space in front of those "AND" statements?
And as far as I can see you are referring to transactiondate table without declaring it in from or a join statement.

EDIT:
You dont referrence both of the tables in the where condition. Dont know how that should work.